# Hyperlink to fire macro in personal.xlsb

Tags: vba, excel, email

I am having a column in an excel with some text(date, sender,subject) which refer to an email. The problem is that(as far as I know) you can hyperlink to an outlook email in public folders, because the email might move(link varies from pc to pc).

So my idea to obtain that email is to make a hyper link that fires of a macro in the personal.xlsb, that then search for that email and display it.

My only problem is that I can not figure out how to link text to start a macro,  `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` means that I need to put that code in the sheet where my text is.

I guess I could do that, but this implements that I need to create this code when the workbook is opened and remove it when the workbook is closed, unless I have to rename all the files xlsx to xlsm, and because I am unsure if other colleagues have link to the excel sheet I would like to avoid doing so.

So my question is, is there any way to make a hyperlink to `personal.xlsb!ShowEmail(cellValue)` ? Or is it possible to make direct link to the email in the public folder? Below is the code for creating the email text:

```
Function getEpostField(projectNumber As String, drawingNumber As String, partNumber As String) As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim myFolderArray() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim myNameSpace As Object
    Dim myFolder As Object
    Dim myNewFolder As Object
    Dim TopPublicFolder As Object
    Dim olMail As Variant
    Dim myTasks
    Dim strFilter As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set myNameSpace = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set TopPublicFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(18)

    getEpostField = ""
    ' array with all subfolders where the item might be...
    myFolderArray = Post.helpRequest("XXXXXXXXX") 
    For i = LBound(myFolderArray) To UBound(myFolderArray)
        Set myFolder = TopPublicFolder.Folders("Prototech").Folders(myFolderArray(i, 2)).Folders
            For j = 1 To myFolder.Count
                If InStr(myFolder(j).Name, projectNumber) Then
                        If drawingNumber <> "" And partNumber <> "" Then
                            strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & drawingNumber & "%' " _
                                & "or " & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & drawingNumber & "%'" _
                                & "or " & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:attachmentfilename" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & drawingNumber & "%'" _
                                & "or " & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & partNumber & "%' " _
                                & "or " & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & partNumber & "%'" _
                                & "or " & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:attachmentfilename" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & partNumber & "%'"
                        ElseIf drawingNumber <> "" Then
                            strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & drawingNumber & "%' " _
                                & "or " & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & drawingNumber & "%'" _
                                & "or " & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:attachmentfilename" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & drawingNumber & "%'"
                        ElseIf partNumber <> "" Then
                             strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & partNumber & "%' " _
                                & "or " & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & partNumber & "%'" _
                                & "or " & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:attachmentfilename" & Chr(34) & " like '%" & partNumber & "%'"
                        Else
                            getEpostField = "No emails found"
                            Exit Function
                        End If


                    Set filteredItems = myFolder(j).Items.Restrict(strFilter)

                    If filteredItems.Count = 0 Then
                        Debug.Print "No emails found"
                        getEpostField = "No emails found"
                        found = False
                    Else
                        found = True
                        ' this loop is optional, it displays the list of emails by subject.
                        For Each itm In filteredItems
                            attachmentString = ""
                            If itm.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                                For Each temp In itm.Attachments
                                    temp2 = InStr(temp.filename, drawingNumber)
                                    If temp2 > 0 Then
                                        attachmentString = attachmentString & temp.filename & " "
                                    End If
                                Next temp
                            End If
                            Debug.Print "Dato:" & Format(itm.CreationTime, "mm.dd.yyyy") & " Subject:" & itm.Subject & " From:" & itm.SenderName & " Attachment:" & attachmentString
                            getEpostField = getEpostField + "Dato:" & Format(itm.CreationTime, "mm.dd.yyyy") & " Subject:" & itm.Subject & " From:" & itm.SenderName & " Attachment:" & attachmentString
                        Next
                    End If


                    'If the subject isn't found:
                    If Not found Then
                        'NoResults.Show
                    Else
                       Debug.Print "Found " & filteredItems.Count & " items."

                    End If
                    Exit Function
                End If

            Next j
        Next i

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=HYPERLINK("#personal.xlsb!modUtility.TestHL()","Test")
```

and a test function (returning a range a just results in the link selecting the already-selected cell)

```
Function TestHL()
    Debug.Print "OK"
    Set TestHL = Selection
End Function
```